# Problems with window resize using vw and vh measures

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im experimenting with vh and vw measures so I have stuck with this problem: when I resize window vertically/open chrome console and then scroll window down background doesn't load in a process of scrolling. How I can recalculate window view ? Or how else I can fix this problem? Is it necessary to use media queries?
Any help will be appreciate.

```css
.m-page-header {
  display: flex;
}

.m-page-header__wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.m-page-header__img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.m-page-header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.main-content {
  display: block;
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/hTboSm/1_HEADER_bg.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main-content__wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-width: 960px;
}

.visually-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main class="main-content">
    <div class="main-content__wrapper">
      <header class="m-page-header">
        <div class="m-page-header__wrapper">
          <section class="m-page-header__img-container">
            <h2 class="page-header__header-text visually-hidden">Game</h2>
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cNjQ7m/1_HEADER_logo.png" alt="Game">
          </section>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `window.onresize` to reposition / recalculate.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't load in a process of scrolling" ? What kind of behavior do you expect from the container background when the window is resized ?

Comment: I mean that background should not crop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions :

**1)** add `background-size: contain` to `.main-content` : 
window resizing will not crop the background anymore. The background will stay completely visible but it won't stretch horizontally.

**https://jsfiddle.net/o0p9y03f/**

**2)** add `background-size: cover` to `.main-content` : 
The background will keep on stretch horizontally but it will be cropped to fill the entire container.

In any case you will have to deal with the size and the centering of the container, depending on which result you are looking for.

**https://jsfiddle.net/o0p9y03f/1/**